# create tag from a branch SVN

Tags: maven, svn

I have a problem with SVN. I want to commit a file (myFile.xml) from a branch and after create a tag of that branch, but when I check the new tag, myFile.xml is not modified... I will write the steps that I am doing:

1.- Checkout the branch
2.- I modify the file and commit it
3.- Checkout the branch again (to check the file and it is right)
4.- With maven mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perfom
5.- I check the new tag and myFile.xml is not modified....

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try something like this see if any better: svn copy  svnlocation/branches/branch svnlocation/tags/new_tag

Comment: Hi justMe, thank you for your reply. My problem is that I want to deploy a WAR from the new tag. If I try your solution, the WAR will not be correct, isn't it?

Comment: I thought you have problem to create the tag from the modified branch. so I suggested to use command line instead. Or just delete the tag and see when you create the new tag have the modification you want. if not then the way you create the tag is pointing to a wrong branch i.e. the old branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the maven release plugin to work correctly, the pom.xml must contain a

```
<scm>
  <developerConnection>
```

tag, and the developerConnection must point exactly to where you want to release from.

If you created your branch "by hand" (not using the release plugin) and didn't update the `developerConnection` in your pom.xml, your `developerConnection` still points to the location you branched from (e.g. trunk).

This is for me a very hot candidate to create exactly the behaviour you describe.

Comment: ouuu yeess! that was what happened! pom.xml of my branch was pointing to trunk :( thank you so much!